# IPersistStorage prevents activex from being rendered in IE11

Tags: com, activex, internet-explorer-11, com-interop, atl

I have a ATL activeX object which contains a default implementation of the IPersistStorage interface. The activeX works fine in IE 8/9/10. But in IE 11 unless I comment out the following:

```
...
//public IPersistStorageImpl<CIsmStreamViewCtl>
...
//COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IPersistStorage)
...
```

the activeX object is not rendered.

However I am using the same activeX object in a C# form. Now if I comment out the IPersistStorage implementation, the form throws an exception during a call to:

```
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)).EndInit()
```

The exception stack trace shows the exception to be thrown at DePersistControl, which require the IPersistStorage interface.

Is there any way to run the ActiveX both in IE and the C# form. The activeX has object safety implemented.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It might be a problem with specific `IPersistStorage` method, fixing which might be a solution.

Comment: @Roman R: Interesting.. I further implemented IPersistPropertyBag and IPersistStreamInit. Just the default implementation and nothing else... Seems to have fixed both issues...

Comment: Well yes, your original description was missing this part. I suppose that having `IPersistStorage` without `IPersistStream`/`IPersistStreamInit` might indeed be the cause.